# JDBC Repository as singleton

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I am writing a simple REST-Service which conntects to an Oracle DB via JDBC. I have a class called DatabaseRepository. This class is a singleton, I open the connection to the database at object creation and keep it alive all the time. In this class there are also methods which retrieve the data from the database and parse the result into objects.

My question now is, if what I do is good practice or not. My thought process was, that it would be better to keep a permanent connection (will be accessed like every 3 seconds) instead of creating a new connection for each call.

Code sample:

```
private static DatabaseRepository instance = null;
private Connection connection = null;

private DatabaseRepository() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    Class.forName(DRIVER_STRING);
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_STRING, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

    // Add a shutdown hook, so the connection is closed when the applications stops
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {

                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.close();
                }

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }));
}

public static DatabaseRepository getInstance() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new DatabaseRepository();
    }

    return instance;
}

public Entity getEntity(long entityId) throws SQLException {

    if (entityId <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Entity id must be greater than 0!");
    }

    PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM tbl_entity WHERE entity_id = ?");
    statement.setLong(1, entityId);
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();

    // If no data was found, return null
    if (!resultSet.next()) {
        return null;
    }

    // Parse the values from the result set
    Entity entity = resultSet. ...

    statement.close();
    resultSet.close();

    return entity;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is good practice to keep a persistent database connection (or even more than one). But it is not so great to write your own code for that, when there are connection pool implementation already available.

Comment: What implementation would you recommend? (new to this topic, never heard of this). How would it make my codes simpler/better

Comment: Take a look at appache commons DBCP (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/)

Comment: Ok, i looked into this, but i don't see how this makes my code better. I see the point of connection pools, but not in my case where I only need one connection the whole time. Do I overlook something here? Why should I prefer this aproach over mine?

Comment: @eckenman, in your approach, how do you plan to manage concurrent requests to the REST-Service ?? Or this will never happen ?? (the same connection cannot be shared simultaneously)